# costum active function in keras using power with decimal point

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, keras, regression

I need to create a custom activation function in Keras that allows raising a sigmoid function to a decimal power. I have run several tests, and when I use decimal points, the prediction results indicate NaN, but if I use integer values in the power, the model works.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Activation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


from keras import backend as K

def custom_activation(x):
    #return (K.sigmoid((x**0.9)))
    return (1 / (1 + K.exp((0.9/0.9)*(K.pow(-x,K.constant(1))))))

dataframe = pd.read_csv("housing.csv", delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values

X = dataset[:, :13]  
Y = dataset[:, 13]  

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

X_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(X)
y_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(Y.reshape(-1, 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation=custom_activation))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))  
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')  

a = model.fit(X_normalized, y_normalized,epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
y_hat = model.predict(X_normalized)
```

In the code, when the values of the exponents are decimals, the results give NaN. I have replicated the costum equation with this example, and it shows that the function does work, but when implementing it in the ANN, it fails.

```
tensor = K.constant(X_normalized)

result_tensor = 1 / (1 + K.exp((0.9/0.5)*(-tensor**0.5)))

[0.5        0.68215114 0.61508656 ... 0.724061   0.8581489  0.6315888 ]
 [0.50691146 0.5        0.7080713  ... 0.7922898  0.8581489  0.6929465 ]
 [0.5069081  0.5        0.7080713  ... 0.7922898  0.85701793 0.61146235]
 ...
 [0.51112956 0.5        0.7626321  ... 0.8457388  0.8581489  0.6436505 ]
 [0.5153265  0.5        0.7626321  ... 0.8457388  0.8571911  0.6573859 ]
 [0.50966954 0.5        0.7626321  ... 0.8457388  0.8581489  0.67732555]], shape=(506, 13), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: What are the values in `X_normalized` in your working example? What would you expect, say ((-1)**0.5) to be? Also, are you aware that you are not in fact raising the result of the sigmoid function to the power, but rather the x argument in the denominator?